# Unable to create Device Fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am following this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/edge-device-fleet-create.html#edge-device-fleet-create-console docs to create device fleet. In this console, Role ARN is optional but it throws `RoleARN is required`. If I provide proper RoleArn it throws `Failed to create/modify RoleAlias. Check your IAM role permission`.

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what is going wrong. Any hint would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohamed, this means that Sagemaker Edge Manager was unable to use the RoleAlias you provided to take the necessary actions when creating a DeviceFleet. It needs to have the AmazonSageMakerEdgeDeviceFleetPolicy attached (or have similar permissions granted) and it needs to trust both SageMaker and IoT Core.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I followed official AWS notebook resources. I was able to resolve the issue.